# Embedding fonts in mx and spark components

Tags: apache-flex, fonts

I'm trying to embed fonts in my app. All is mostly well but for the itemRenderers in my AdvancedDataGrid. [Adobe's documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSda78ed3a750d6b8f-26a13bbf123c441239d-8000.html) claims that

> The MX DataGrid control has a special
>   class, FTEDataGridItemRenderer, that
>   you can use for custom item renderers.
>   The MXFTEText.css theme file specifies
>   it as follows:
>   defaultDataGridItemRenderer:
>   ClassReference("mx.controls.dataGridClasses.FTEDataGridItemRenderer");

they, however, don't mention anything for ADGs, and setting defaultDataGridItemRenderer to either FTEDataGridItemRenderer or FTEAdvancedDataGridItemRenderer doesn't seem to do the trick. Would love to know if anyone has had to deal with this and managed to successfully get around this.

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured it out...

```
mx|AdvancedDataGrid
{
        defaultDataGridItemEditor: ClassReference("mx.controls.MXFTETextInput");
        defaultDataGridItemRenderer: ClassReference("mx.controls.advancedDataGridClasses.FTEAdvancedDataGridItemRenderer");
}
```

does the trick. Strangely if you only use the itemRenderer part the IRs actually don't use FTE to render.